# JQuery - Add onclick to dynamically generated img tag

Tags: jquery

I am creating several image dynamically using the following code:

```
function refresh_gallery(galleryidentifier, albumid) {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "/Photos/Thumbnails/" + albumid + "/", data: {}, success: function(msg) {
        try {
            var fotos = eval(msg); $(galleryidentifier).empty(); if (fotos.length == 0) { $(galleryidentifier).html("Press &quot;Add files...&quot; and select files to upload!"); return true; }
            for (var f in fotos) {
                //this image needs the onclick eventhandler
                $(document.createElement("img")).attr({ src: '/images/delete.gif', title: 'Delete ' + fotos[f].Title }).addClass("icon_delete").appendTo(galleryidentifier); ;
                $(document.createElement("img")).attr({ src: fotos[f].ThumbnailPath, title: fotos[f].Title }).addClass("thumbnail").appendTo(galleryidentifier);
            }
            var del_div = $(document.createElement("div")).css({ "padding": "4px" }).appendTo(galleryidentifier);
            var delete_span = $(document.createElement("span")).click(delete_files(albumid)).css({ "cursor": "pointer", "font-size": "12px" }).appendTo(del_div);
            $(document.createElement("img")).attr({ "src": "/Content/images/delete.png" }).appendTo(delete_span);
            $(document.createTextNode("delete all")).appendTo(delete_span);
            return true;
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
        alert("Refresh error!");
    }, error: function() { alert("Refresh error!"); }
    });
}
```

The generation of the images is working fine, but I want to add an onclick eventhandler to the first image being generated (see comment in code).
How do I do this? I'm fairly new to JQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$(document.createElement("img"))
    .attr({ src: '/images/delete.gif', title: 'Delete ' + fotos[f].Title })
    .addClass("icon_delete")
    .appendTo(galleryidentifier)
    .click(function(){
        // Do something
    })
```

Answer (score 10):

jQuery has a method called click, the argument to which is a callback function. In this example, I'm also going to use a (much) simpler shorthand for creating an image element:

```
$('<img/>').click(function () {
    // do something
}).attr({
    src: '/images/delete.gif',
    title: 'Delete ' + fotos[f].Title
}).addClass("icon_delete").appendTo(galleryidentifier);
```

Answer (score 6):

Ever since jQuery 1.4 you can create an element and add all atrributes/events to it when creating.

In the case of an image tag you would write:

```
$('<img/>', {
    src:     '/images/delete.gif',
    title:   'Delete ' + fotos[f].Title,
    'class': 'icon_delete', // in quotes because class is a reserved js word
    click:   function( e ){
        // Everything here happens when you click the image.
    }
}).appendTo(galleryidentifier);
```

Above [example](http://jsbin.com/esicoq) in JSBin.

Here's the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#entry-examples-1) to the docs.

Why it's better than the other ways of creating an image using jQuery:

- Much cleaner than chaining a dozen methods.
- Allows you to send in objects with different properties to be created.
- Matches up nicely with a regular html "Hard coded" element.

Comment: This looks pretty neat indeed!

Comment: @pankysharma That's just's just regular javascript object notation. JSON is based on this notation model.

Comment: Actually, JavaScript Object Notation = JSON, its not based on it, its IS it.  What you might be referring to is javascript structure notation, which includes function implementations.  Javascript Object Notation does not allow the inclusion of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event handler of this type using the [click](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#fn) function in the same way you added the css class.

Answer (score 1):

you could just create a class when creating your image with addClass() method.
And elsewhere have something like

```
$(document).ready(
  $("img.toBeClicked").click(function() {
    //some code
  };
};
```