# run a script before page start to redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there any way to show a loading element when user click on a link or any thing that cause page start to reload , until browser start to show server response?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - you have enough rep to edit that.

Comment: I thought he meant "floating".

Comment: Browsers have those built in…

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866252/jquery-add-onclick-to-dynamically-generated-img-tag][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866252/jquery-add-onclick-to-dynamically-generated-img-tag

When the page is reloaded the image naturally disappear.

Comment: Are you ok with non-javascirpt solutions?You have a javascript tag but your question does not say I wish to use JavaScript?

Comment: sorry , i wan not at desk, Ook, now i will check your answers

Comment: Ok,first sorry about bad syntaxes, and tanks Oded to resolve them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write a JavaScript function that shows the element that contains your loading mock up when you click let's say a button.

The page render will override that as soon as the server response back.

if you are familiar with JQuery and Ajax the best way would be to use an asyn post.

- Use Jquery to show the loading mock up
- Async post to the server
- Use Jquery to get the response,hide the loading mock up, refresh the portion of the page you need to